# IE <a> element float left first get shifted for some reason

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have some `<a>` elements that's float left. For some reason the first element get shifted upwards in IE10.
Need to float them because some of the the elements are not displayed, otherwise the view gets nasty.

**Html**

```html
   <div id="Header-Links">
      <a id="Links-Start" href="#Start">Start</a>
      <a id="Links-Orders" href="#Orders" class="DisplayNone"></a>
      <a id="Links-References" href="#References"></a>
      <a id="Links-Account" href="#Account" class="DisplayNone"></a>
      <a id="Links-Customer" href="#Customer"></a>
      <a id="Links-Support" href="#Support"></a>
      <a id="Links-Impress" href="#Impress"></a>
   </div>
```

CSS

```css
#Header-Links {
  top: 13px;
  left: 30px;
}

#Header-Links > a {
  text-decoration: none;
  float: left;
}

#Header-Links a + a:before {
  content: "|";
  margin-left: 7px;
  margin-right: 6px;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.DisplayNone {
   display: none;
}
```

Google Chrome
[image]

Internet Explorer
[image]

Comment: Is that a typo or the actual code: `Link-Start` vs. `Links-Start`?

Comment: no its just here. fix it.

Comment: [This jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H4xR2/) is displayed correctly in IE10. I think you need to include the surrounded tags + styles.

Comment: You're right, this sucks. Need inspect my css little bit further.

Comment: I seem to have a problem when my text gets translated to another language in IE as well

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere the elements get a different line-height than the first.